# How to get webpage to shrink as per the window size (when seen on a mobile)?

Tags: html

```
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:7.5pt;text-align:justify'>
<span lang=EN-GB style='font-size:13.5pt;line-height:115%;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";color:black'>
```

```
Note: Wherever it is found, "<" denotes aggravation
```

```
<o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

````html
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0in;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:
    3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>

  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;height:18.75pt'>

    <td colspan=3 style='width:100%;border:none;border-bottom:solid #BCD3E5 1.0pt;
    mso-border-bottom-alt:solid #BCD3E5 .75pt;background:#EBF4FB;padding:3.75pt 7.5pt 3.75pt 
    7.5pt;height:18.75pt'>

      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:
    "Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:#075296;
    mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

Twitching, fasciculations, tremors, spasms, convulsions, chorea, grimaces. 

    <br>

    <br>


Anxiety and excitement. Ecstasy.

    <br>
    <br>

Dependent and fearful. 

    <br>

    <br>

Awkwardness in arms and legs.

    <br>
    <br>

&lt; before thunderstorms

    <br>
    <br>

Diagonal affections. 

    <br>
    <br>

Low back pain &lt; sitting. 

    </span></p>

    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1'>

    <td width=101 colspan=2 valign=top style='width:75.75pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>

      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal'><b><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:red;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

SYNONYM 

    </span></b></p>

    </td>

    <td width=473 valign=top style='width:354.5pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>

      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:
  "Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:black;
  mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

Amanita Muscaria.

    </span></p>

    </td>

    <td width=11 style='width:8.5pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'></td>

  </tr>

  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:2'>

    <td width=101 colspan=2 valign=top style='width:75.75pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>

      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal'><b><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:red;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

COMMON NAME 

    </span></b><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:
  "Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-ansi-language:
  EN-US'><o:p></o:p></span></p>

    </td>

    <td width=473 valign=top style='width:354.5pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>

      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:black;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

Toadstool

    </span></p>

    </td>

    <td width=11 style='width:8.5pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'></td>

  </tr>

  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:3'>

    <td width=101 colspan=2 valign=top style='width:75.75pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>

      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal'><b><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:red;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

FAMILY 

    </span></b></p>

    </td>

    <td width=473 valign=top style='width:354.5pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>

      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:black;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

Fungi 

    </span></p>

    </td>

    <td width=11 style='width:8.5pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'></td>

  </tr>```
  <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0in;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
    <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;height:18.75pt'>
      <td colspan=3 style='width:100%;border:none;border-bottom:solid #BCD3E5 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid #BCD3E5 .75pt;background:#EBF4FB;padding:3.75pt 7.5pt 3.75pt 7.5pt;height:18.75pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:
  "Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:#075296;
  mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

Twitching, fasciculations, tremors, spasms, convulsions, chorea, grimaces. <br>

    <br>

Anxiety and excitement. Ecstasy. 

    <br>
    <br>

Dependent and fearful. 

    <br>
    <br>

Awkwardness in arms and legs.

    <br>
    <br>

&lt; before thunderstorms
    <br>
    <br>

Diagonal affections.

    <br>
    <br>

Low back pain &lt; sitting.

    </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1'>
      <td width=101 colspan=2 valign=top style='width:75.75pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal'><b><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";
  mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
  color:red;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

SYNONYM 
    </span></b></p>
      </td>
      <td width=473 valign=top style='width:354.5pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:black;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>
Amanita Muscaria. 

    </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:2'>
      <td width=101 colspan=2 valign=top style='width:75.75pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal'><b><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:red;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

COMMON NAME 

    </span></b></p>
      </td>
      <td width=473 valign=top style='width:354.5pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:black;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

Toadstool

    </span></p>
      </td>
      <td width=11 style='width:8.5pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:3'>
      <td width=101 colspan=2 valign=top style='width:75.75pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal'><b><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:red;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

FAMILY

    </span></b></p>
      </td>
      <td width=473 valign=top style='width:354.5pt;border:solid #BFDBFF 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid #BFDBFF .75pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:black;mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>

Fungi

  </span></p>

      </td>

      <td width=11 style='width:8.5pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'></td>

    </tr>
  </table>
````

Comment: look into media queries using CSS, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) is a good start

Comment: https://cure4incurables.in/AGARICUS-MUSCARIUS.html is working fine but the edited https://cure4incurables.in/AGARICUS-MUSCARIUS1.html is not shrinking to fit the window - the only difference between the two is that every leading hyphen/dash is encapsulated in a <table>.....</table> for the second webpage. I've edited and posted the above with great difficulty and hope someone can spoon feed me an answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, you want to know how to make a webpage responsive then [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is a good way.

Comment: I'm using a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editor, "Komppzer" and it helps me design everything perfectly but I have a bug. Please compare cure4incurables.in/AGARICUS-MUSCARIUS.html which is working perfectly and cure4incurables.in/AGARICUS-MUSCARIUS1.html - the text at the edited cure4incurables.in/AGARICUS-MUSCARIUS1.html is extending into the table that floats on the right and doesn't shrink to fit a mobile screen

Comment: This webpage: https://cure4incurables.in/AESCULUS-HIPPOCASTANUM.html is an example of how everything is working fine even after encapsulating the leading hyphen/dash in a <table>.....</table> block

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but why can't you use the one that is working? I am just trying to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I thought I had explained it. I edited a webpage after which it is extending beyond the set 100% width. How do I get it to shrink to fit on a mobile screen? The sentence (Note meant for the webpage visitors) at the top is shrinking to fit the mobile but not the rest

Comment: The webpage with the error is https://cure4incurables.in/AGARICUS-MUSCARIUS1.html - please take a look at it to understand what I mean

Comment: I believe that that WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editor, "Komppzer" creates the HTML codes in pixels instead of in percentage which is causing the problem.

Comment: At least, someone please tell me where or how I can get a free HTML editor which generates the HTML code for the width of tables and <td> elements in % instead of pixels (MS word Doc conversion or something that generates the HTML code as soon as I paste it)